# MongoDB query that contain at least one of filters specified in an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB that is structured like this:

```
  "5d33488672886334cd21904xx": {
    "ownerId": "5d333551k99951924fb3208",
    "createdAt": 1582456098,
    ....phone
    ....email
    ....etc
    "mainActivities": {
      "dogWalking": true
    },
    "secActivities": {
      "washing": true,
      "houseSitting": true,
      "dogSitting": true,
      "training": true,
      "trainingEquipment": true,
      "selectionAdvice": true,
      "institutionsBusinesses": true
    }
}

  "5d33488672886334cd21904xx": {
    "ownerId": "5d333d344d46ed924fb3208",
    "createdAt": 99999995,
    ....phone
    ....email
    ....etc
    "mainActivities": {
      "dogWalking": true
    },
    "secActivities": {
      "washing": false,
      "houseSitting": false,
      "dogSitting": false,
      "training": true,
      "trainingEquipment": false,
      "selectionAdvice": true,
      "institutionsBusinesses": true
    }
}
```

i am sending filters from the front end like so :

```
{
  "filters": {
    "mainActivities": {
      "dogWalking": true
    },
    "secActivities": {
      "washing":           false,
      "houseSitting":      true,
      "dogSitting":        true,
      "training":          true,
      "trainingEquipment": true,
      "selectionAdvice":   false,
      "institutionsBusinesses": true
    }
  }
}
```

i want to get all the documents that answer the filters and not EXACT match .

Example:
if i am a dog walker service named "Xdog" , who give all the 6/6 activities (secActivities)

in the front end , when user select 2/6 filters i miss this "Xdog" service.

i get to a function who return only the document that specify EXACT match and its not good because
i am missing the services who actually answer this 2/6 filters..

right now i am sending and spreading the "filterBy" variable into the find() function .

Any suggestion would be great i am weak in Databases commands.

Sorry for my poor English!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do partial match is with `$or`, but I don't think that will do what you actually want.

The example query you showed above is looking for dog walking services that *do not* provide washing or selectionAdvice services.  Your description suggests that you do not want to consider these 2 services because the user did not specify them.  In that case, leave these 2 out of the query entirely, using the user selections to add only the relevant fields, like:

```
.find({
    "mainActivities": {
      "dogWalking": true
    },
    "secActivities": {
      "houseSitting":      true,
      "dogSitting":        true,
      "training":          true,
      "trainingEquipment": true,
      "institutionsBusinesses": true
    }
  }
```

If the filters object is already built, you would need to remove the properties that are false.  See [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)